# Declared javascript function calling itself

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why this works

```
(function Test() { 
    alert('x'); 
}())
```

but this doesn't work

```
function Test() { 
    alert('x'); 
}()
```

How does the outer parenthesis change the precedence of things and make it work?

Comment: Any statement that **starts with** `function` is a function *declaration*, and is not callable. If the function appears in an *expression*, it's a function expression, and is callable. Starting the statement with a paren makes it an expression. You can also do `!function Test(){ alert(x) }()`, but that's a less common hack than wrapping the whole thing in parens.

Comment: Take a look at [function definitions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) at the **Self-Invoking Functions** part

Comment: P.S. Please remove the jQuery tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can image the parenthesis is use for be explicit on what you do. Like when you do some operation like 3 * 2 + 4 or 3 * (2 + 4).
When you do

```
function Test() { alert('x'); }()
```

The navigator just see 2 parenthesis alone whereas when you do

```
(function Test() { alert('x'); }())
```

It see you want to execute the function.